# need application url from console application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC web application and a console application created as a separate project inside my web application. I want this console application to be run as a windows service at specified intervals. The console application is for sending mail to some persons. I need to include my application URL in the mail content body which redirect to my application login page. Since i am running this service for more than one instance i could't hard code the URL in code. Someone please help. I tried the below code. But it is returning null value.

```
 var site = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
                var url = string.Format("<a href='{0}'>Login</a>", site);
```

Comment: You are trying to obtain information from `HttpContext.Current` in situation when there is no HttpContext available at all - because your console application is launched directly by the operating system and not on the event of incoming http request (as oposed to request handling in your MVC application) - so it is ilogical to try to use something that is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I converted this from the comment to the question.

You are trying to obtain information from `HttpContext.Current` in situation when there is no HttpContext available at all - because your console application is launched directly by the operating system and not on the event of incoming http request (as oposed to request handling in your MVC application) - so there simply is no http context to use (hence `HttpContext.Current` is null in your console application).

You have to establish your own application logic for your console application that determines which URL to use in your emails. What would that be depends on the answer to the question "what does the url to be used in each email depend on specifically"? In other words - "how should each email know what URL to use"? Once you figure out the answer to that question then you can think of how to pass that dependency to your windows service.

Example (I do not know if it describes your case):

- there are several web applications on different URLs
- each of these web applications can add email to the queue to be send
- windows service (console app) is scheduled to run once in a while and process the queue by sending the emails. Each email has to have an URL of the application from where it was added.

Assuming the example above you can just add the email together with the URL of the application to the queue (insted of just the email) and then retrieve that information from the queue in your console application. So then each of the emails has associated URL. It is irrelevant how would the queue itself be implemented (SQL, file, ...).